# Android Video stops playing after multiple plays Error 1, 2147483648

Tags: android, android-videoview, android-mediaplayer

OK, this is a little frustrating, and I have searched Stack but none of the answers seems to help.

I have an Android app which cycles through different content on the screen. At one point it plays a video, the same video, loaded from the same place.

After a random number of plays, it decides to stop playing the video file and throws the error up above (-2147483648) which is a generic file not found / incorrect format error.

The problem is the video plays correctly numerous times before this error comes up. I have tried a number of alternatives to fixing this:

- a VideoView playing a file (the start)
- a MediaPlayer + SurfaceView combo reading from file
- MediaPlayer + SurfaceView reading from file descriptor
- forcing permissions to world readable
- copying the file to a temporary file and playing this
- manually releasing the mediaplayer for both the VideoView and MediaPlayer options
- running manual garbage collection after each play

and yet still, after multiple plays, eventually, it will refuse to play the video.

One change which might or might no be relevant is when playing from a file descriptor it throws a mediaplayer prepare Java I/O Exception which I believe is related to perhaps there is somehow some locking happening on the file.

The only way to fix this is to reboot the device. Restarting the app does not fix it and it immediately will refuse to play the file.

Here is the VideoView playing code:

```
// from main activity
File afile = new File(btvapp.fileroot,btvapp.getDailyVideo().get("FILENAME"));        
afile.setReadable(true, false);
theVideo = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoViewer);
theVideo.requestFocus();
theVideo.setVideoPath(afile.getPath());
theVideo.setOnPreparedListener(this);
theVideo.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //mp.release();
        theVideo.stopPlayback();
        mp.release();
            finish();

    }
} );
theVideo.setOnErrorListener(new MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
            finish();
            return false;
        }
    });

// play on prepared function
@Override
  public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  mp.start();
}
```

The surface view uses the Android SDK mediaplaying example almost exactly, but I don't think it's worth pasting the code, since the error happens regardless of whether you use the mediaplayer + surfaceview method OR the VideoView playback method.

Thoughts? Driving me crazy.

**UPDATE**: Here's the full log including the main app and the spawned video activity

```
07-19 18:47:02.844: V/videpath(7232): /mnt/sdcard/Android/data/au.com.nian.bullertv/files/tmpbtag.mp4
07-19 18:47:03.014: I/dalvikvm(7232): threadid=1: recursive native library load attempt (/system/lib/libmedia_jni.so)
07-19 18:47:03.014: D/MtpDeviceJNI(7232): register_android_mtp_MtpDevice
07-19 18:47:03.014: I/dalvikvm(7232): threadid=1: recursive native library load attempt (/system/lib/libmedia_jni.so)
07-19 18:47:03.014: I/dalvikvm(7232): threadid=1: recursive native library load attempt (/system/lib/libmedia_jni.so)
07-19 18:47:03.024: V/MediaPlayerService(87): Client(56) constructor
07-19 18:47:03.024: V/MediaPlayerService(87): Create new client(56) from pid 7232, uid 10043, 
07-19 18:47:03.034: V/MediaPlayerService(87): setDataSource(/mnt/sdcard/Android/data/au.com.nian.bullertv/files/tmpbtag.mp4)
07-19 18:47:03.034: V/MediaPlayerService(87): media.amsuperplayer.enable is enabled
07-19 18:47:03.034: V/MediaPlayerService(87): media.amsuperplayer.enable is enabled
07-19 18:47:03.034: V/MediaPlayerService(87): player type = 6
07-19 18:47:03.034: V/MediaPlayerService(87): Create AmSuperPlayer
07-19 18:47:03.034: V/AmSuperPlayer(87): [AmSuperPlayer::74]
07-19 18:47:03.034: V/AmSuperPlayer(87): [AmSuperPlayer::76]
07-19 18:47:03.034: V/AmSuperPlayer(87): AmSuperPlayer init now
07-19 18:47:03.034: V/AmSuperPlayer(87): [onFirstRef::103]
07-19 18:47:03.034: V/AmSuperPlayer(87): [initCheck::110]
07-19 18:47:03.034: V/AmSuperPlayer(87): [initCheck::112]
07-19 18:47:03.034: V/AmSuperPlayer(87): [setNotifyCallback::455]
07-19 18:47:03.034: V/AmSuperPlayer(87): [hardwareOutput::330]
07-19 18:47:03.034: V/AmSuperPlayer(87): [hardwareOutput::332]
07-19 18:47:03.034: V/AudioSink(87): AudioOutput(112)
07-19 18:47:03.034: V/MediaPlayerService(87):  setDataSource
07-19 18:47:03.034: V/AmSuperPlayer(87): [setDataSource::118]
07-19 18:47:03.034: V/AmSuperPlayer(87): [setDataSource::120]
07-19 18:47:03.034: V/MediaPlayerService(87): [56] setVideoSurfaceTexture(0x28290)
07-19 18:47:03.034: V/AmSuperPlayer(87): [setVideoSurfaceTexture::168]
07-19 18:47:03.034: V/AmSuperPlayer(87): [setVideoSurfaceTexture::170]
07-19 18:47:03.034: V/MediaPlayerService(87): [56] setVideoSurfaceTexture(0x29660)
07-19 18:47:03.034: V/MediaPlayerService(87): [56] setAudioStreamType(3)
07-19 18:47:03.034: V/MediaPlayerService(87): [56] prepareAsync
07-19 18:47:03.034: V/AmSuperPlayer(87): [prepareAsync::199]
07-19 18:47:03.034: V/AmSuperPlayer(87): [prepareAsync::202]
07-19 18:47:03.034: V/AmSuperPlayer(87): initThread(7388) started
07-19 18:47:03.034: V/AmSuperPlayer(87): createPlayer
07-19 18:47:03.034: V/AmSuperPlayer(87): Create Amlogic Player
07-19 18:47:03.034: V/AmlogicPlayer(87): AmlogicPlayer constructor
07-19 18:47:03.034: I/AmlogicPlayer(87): media.amplayer.stopbuflevel is not set
07-19 18:47:03.034: V/AmlogicPlayer(87): onFirstRef
07-19 18:47:03.034: I/AmlogicPlayer(87): found 0 not exit player threads,try exit it now
07-19 18:47:03.034: V/AmlogicPlayer(87): initCheck
07-19 18:47:03.034: V/AmSuperPlayer(87): [CreatePlayer::678]
07-19 18:47:03.034: V/AmlogicPlayer(87): setDataSource
07-19 18:47:03.034: V/AmlogicPlayer(87): History mgt old[,0,-1]
07-19 18:47:03.034: V/AmlogicPlayer(87): History mgt    [/mnt/sdcard/Android/data/au.com.nian.bullertv/files/tmpbtag.mp4,0,0]
07-19 18:47:03.034: V/AmlogicPlayer(87): setDataSource url=/mnt/sdcard/Android/data/au.com.nian.bullertv/files/tmpbtag.mp4, len=63
07-19 18:47:03.034: V/AmlogicPlayer(87): Set setVideoSurfaceTexture
07-19 18:47:03.034: I/AmlogicPlayer(87): media.amplayer.lpbufferlevel is not set
07-19 18:47:03.034: I/AmlogicPlayer(87): media.amplayer.buffertime is not set
07-19 18:47:03.034: V/AmlogicPlayer(87): prepareAsync
07-19 18:47:03.034: I/AmlogicPlayer(87): media.amplayer.noaudio is disabled
07-19 18:47:03.034: I/AmlogicPlayer(87): media.amplayer.novideo is disabled
07-19 18:47:03.034: V/AmlogicPlayer(87): buffer level setting is:0.001000-0.020000-0.800000
07-19 18:47:03.034: V/AmlogicPlayer(87): prepareAsync,file_name=/mnt/sdcard/Android/data/au.com.nian.bullertv/files/tmpbtag.mp4
07-19 18:47:03.034: I/amplayer(87): LibPlayer version:Version:2.1.0.
07-19 18:47:03.034: I/amplayer(87): LibPlayer git version:
07-19 18:47:03.034: I/amplayer(87): LibPlayer version serial:201000000000000
07-19 18:47:03.034: I/amplayer(87): LibPlayer Last Changed:
07-19 18:47:03.034: I/amplayer(87): LibPlayer Last Build: Tue May 22 17:40:26 HKT 2012
07-19 18:47:03.034: I/amplayer(87): LibPlayer Builer Name: clei
07-19 18:47:03.034: I/amplayer(87): [player_start:enter]p=0x2a98dc black=0
07-19 18:47:03.034: I/amplayer(87): ***player_para=0x112d28,start_param=0x2a98dc
07-19 18:47:03.034: I/amplayer(87): [player_thread_create:70]creat thread success,tid=149280
07-19 18:47:03.034: I/amplayer(87): [player_start:exit]pid = 23 
07-19 18:47:03.034: V/AmlogicPlayer(87): Start player,pid=23
07-19 18:47:03.034: I/amplayer(87): pid[23]::enter into player_thread
07-19 18:47:03.034: I/amplayer(87): pid[23]::Init State: mute_on=0 black=0 t_pos:1074106323s read_max_cnt=0
07-19 18:47:03.034: I/amplayer(87): file::::[/mnt/sdcard/Android/data/au.com.nian.bullertv/files/tmpbtag.mp4],len=63
07-19 18:47:03.154: I/amplayer(87): **[update_state]pid:23 status=BEGIN_INIT(last:UNKNOW_STATE) err=0x0 curtime=0 (ms:0) fulltime=0 lsttime=0
07-19 18:47:03.154: I/amplayer(87): **[update_state]abuflevel=0.000 vbublevel=0.000 abufrp=0 vbufrp=0 read_end=0
07-19 18:47:03.154: V/AmlogicPlayer(87): update_process pid=23, current=0,status=[BEGIN_INIT]
07-19 18:47:03.154: V/AmlogicPlayer(87): Playing percent =0,mPlayTime:0,mStreamTime:0
07-19 18:47:03.154: V/AmSuperPlayer(87): [notify::404]
07-19 18:47:03.154: V/AmSuperPlayer(87): [Notify::411]
07-19 18:47:03.154: V/AmSuperPlayer(87): cookie=0x475e0,msg=3,ext1=0,ext2=0
07-19 18:47:03.154: I/amplayer(87): [ffmpeg_open_file] file=/mnt/sdcard/Android/data/au.com.nian.bullertv/files/tmpbtag.mp4,header=
07-19 18:47:03.154: I/amplayer(87): ffmpeg error: Couldn't open input file! ret==ffffffe8
07-19 18:47:03.154: I/amplayer(87): [player_dec_init]ffmpeg_open_file failed(/mnt/sdcard/Android/data/au.com.nian.bullertv/files/tmpbtag.mp4)*****ret=fcffffff!
07-19 18:47:03.154: I/amplayer(87): pid[23]player_thread release0 begin...(sta:0x30001)
07-19 18:47:03.154: I/amplayer(87): [get_pts_video]No codec handler
07-19 18:47:03.154: I/amplayer(87): **[update_state]pid:23 status=ERROR(last:BEGIN_INIT) err=0x3000001 curtime=0 (ms:0) fulltime=0 lsttime=0
07-19 18:47:03.154: I/amplayer(87): **[update_state]abuflevel=0.000 vbublevel=0.000 abufrp=0 vbufrp=0 read_end=0
07-19 18:47:03.154: V/AmlogicPlayer(87): update_process pid=23, current=0,status=[ERROR]
07-19 18:47:03.154: V/AmSuperPlayer(87): [notify::404]
07-19 18:47:03.154: V/AmSuperPlayer(87): [Notify::411]
07-19 18:47:03.154: V/AmSuperPlayer(87): cookie=0x475e0,msg=64,ext1=1,ext2=fcffffff
07-19 18:47:03.154: V/AmSuperPlayer(87): [CreatePlayer::702]
07-19 18:47:03.154: I/AmSuperPlayer(87): media.amplayer.enable is enabled
07-19 18:47:03.154: I/AmSuperPlayer(87): media.stagefright.enable-player is disabled
07-19 18:47:03.154: V/AmSuperPlayer(87): [CreatePlayer::713]
07-19 18:47:03.154: V/AmSuperPlayer(87): Need to creat new player=3
07-19 18:47:03.154: V/AmlogicPlayer(87): stop
07-19 18:47:03.154: I/amplayer(87): [player_stop:enter]pid=23
07-19 18:47:03.154: I/amplayer(87): [player_stop]player_status=30001
07-19 18:47:03.154: I/amplayer(87): [player_stop]pid=23 thread is already stopped
07-19 18:47:03.154: V/AmlogicPlayer(87): AmlogicPlayer destructor
07-19 18:47:03.154: V/AmlogicPlayer(87): release
07-19 18:47:03.154: V/AmlogicPlayer(87): [release::1461]
07-19 18:47:03.154: I/amplayer(87): [player_stop:enter]pid=23
07-19 18:47:03.154: I/amplayer(87): [player_stop]player_status=30001
07-19 18:47:03.154: I/amplayer(87): [player_stop]pid=23 thread is already stopped
07-19 18:47:03.154: I/amplayer(87): [player_exit:enter]pid=23
07-19 18:47:03.154: I/amplayer(87): [player_exit]player_state=0x30001
07-19 18:47:03.154: I/amplayer(87): [player_stop:enter]pid=23
07-19 18:47:03.154: I/amplayer(87): [player_stop]player_status=30001
07-19 18:47:03.154: I/amplayer(87): [player_stop]pid=23 thread is already stopped
07-19 18:47:03.154: I/amplayer(87): [player_thread_wait_exit:80]pid=[23] thead_id=149280
07-19 18:47:03.154: V/AmlogicPlayer(87): Player status:ERROR, error occur
07-19 18:47:03.154: V/AmSuperPlayer(87): [notify::404]
07-19 18:47:03.154: V/AmSuperPlayer(87): [Notify::411]
07-19 18:47:03.154: V/AmSuperPlayer(87): cookie=0x475e0,msg=64,ext1=1,ext2=ffffffff
07-19 18:47:03.154: I/amplayer(87): **[update_state]pid:23 status=EXIT(last:ERROR) err=0x0 curtime=0 (ms:0) fulltime=0 lsttime=0
07-19 18:47:03.154: I/amplayer(87): **[update_state]abuflevel=0.000 vbublevel=0.000 abufrp=0 vbufrp=0 read_end=0
07-19 18:47:03.154: V/AmlogicPlayer(87): update_process pid=23, current=0,status=[EXIT]
07-19 18:47:03.154: V/AmlogicPlayer(87): Player status:EXIT, playback exit
07-19 18:47:03.154: I/amplayer(87): pid[23]::stop play, exit player thead!(sta:0x30004)
07-19 18:47:03.154: I/amplayer(87): [player_thread_wait_exit:86]thead_id=149280 returning
07-19 18:47:03.154: I/amplayer(87): [player_exit]player thread already exit: 0
07-19 18:47:03.154: I/amplayer(87): [player_release_pid:72]release pid=23
07-19 18:47:03.154: I/amplayer(87): [player_exit:exit]pid=23
07-19 18:47:03.154: V/AmlogicPlayer(87): set fs/sys/class/video/disable_video=2 failed
07-19 18:47:03.154: I/amplayer(87): ENABLE_FREE_SCALE not define!
07-19 18:47:03.154: I/amplayer(87): [get_display_mode]display_mode=fail
07-19 18:47:03.154: I/amplayer(87): open /sys/class/graphics/fb0/scale fail.
07-19 18:47:03.154: I/amplayer(87): open /sys/class/graphics/fb1/scale fail.
07-19 18:47:03.154: I/amplayer(87): open /sys/class/graphics/fb1/scale_axis fail.
07-19 18:47:03.154: I/amplayer(87): open /sys/class/graphics/fb0/blank fail.
07-19 18:47:03.154: I/amplayer(87): open /sys/class/graphics/fb1/blank fail.
07-19 18:47:03.154: I/amplayer(87): [get_display_mode]display_mode=fail
07-19 18:47:03.154: I/amplayer(87): open /sys/class/graphics/fb0/free_scale fail.
07-19 18:47:03.154: I/amplayer(87): open /sys/class/graphics/fb1/free_scale fail.
07-19 18:47:03.154: I/amplayer(87): open /sys/class/video/axis fail.
07-19 18:47:03.154: I/amplayer(87): open /sys/class/ppmgr/ppscaler fail.
07-19 18:47:03.154: I/amplayer(87): open /sys/class/ppmgr/ppscaler_rect fail.
07-19 18:47:03.154: I/amplayer(87): display mode: 292344
07-19 18:47:03.154: I/amplayer(87): [enable_freescale_MBX]set video axis: 0 0 0 0 
07-19 18:47:03.154: V/AmlogicPlayer(87): VideoViewClose=-33554433
07-19 18:47:03.154: V/AmlogicPlayer(87): [release::1471]
07-19 18:47:03.154: V/AmlogicPlayer(87): History mgt old[,0,-1]
07-19 18:47:03.154: V/AmlogicPlayer(87): History mgt    [/mnt/sdcard/Android/data/au.com.nian.bullertv/files/tmpbtag.mp4,1,0]
07-19 18:47:03.154: V/AmSuperPlayer(87): createPlayer
07-19 18:47:03.154: V/AmSuperPlayer(87):  create StagefrightPlayer
07-19 18:47:03.154: V/AmSuperPlayer(87): [CreatePlayer::678]
07-19 18:47:03.154: I/AwesomePlayer(87): setDataSource_l('/mnt/sdcard/Android/data/au.com.nian.bullertv/files/tmpbtag.mp4')
07-19 18:47:03.154: V/AmSuperPlayer(87): [CreatePlayer::713]
07-19 18:47:03.154: V/AmSuperPlayer(87): [CreatePlayer::729]
07-19 18:47:03.154: V/AmSuperPlayer(87): Start new player now=3
07-19 18:47:03.154: V/AmSuperPlayer(87): [initThread::762]
07-19 18:47:03.154: V/AmSuperPlayer(87): [notify::404]
07-19 18:47:03.154: V/AmSuperPlayer(87): [Notify::411]
07-19 18:47:03.154: V/AmSuperPlayer(87): cookie=0x475e0,msg=64,ext1=1,ext2=80000000
07-19 18:47:03.154: V/MediaPlayerService(87): [56] notify (0x23d50, 100, 1, -2147483648)
07-19 18:47:03.154: **E/MediaPlayer(7232): error (1, -2147483648)**
07-19 18:47:03.154: V/videoerr(7232): java.io.IOException: Prepare failed.: status=0x1
```

**UPDATE 2:**
I have tested the code on 2 other Android devices (one ICS, one Gingerbread) and annoyingly it works fine on them and ran for over 12 hours without incident. So, it looks to be a platform error, but still need to solve this.

Comment: can you paste log of the error , please include the lines which are above the error

Comment: I'm just running it again, will paste the log shortly, note I am running surfaceview right now. It might take half an hour to crash.

Comment: OK updated. Note, I had to grab this log from the restart but the error is the same. Looking in it says 'no codec failure' but of course, it has played the video correctly 37 times before this.

Comment: All this leads me to thinking it's some kind of file lock or caching error... when I play it through the file browser on the Android it plays fine however, but still crashes when the app starts.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what device did you try this on?

Comment: @Auras - the device is a Genitech ATV-1000.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm almost positive this is an issue with the Amlogic based device you are using (evident due to the "amplayer" and "AmlogicPlayer" in the logcat).  We have had tons of issues with an Amlogic AML8726 based device we are testing.  Try upgrading the firmware if possible.

Comment: Indeed that is the chipset on the box being used. Have upgraded firmware to the latest available from manuf. but this did not resolve the issue. It has a few other issues too.

Comment: the Amlogic based devices still have issues with their AmlogicPlayer, and the buffering from live streams are still super slow compared to other devices. loading times of the same stream is 8 seconds in all the Amlogic devices ive tested (4 in total), 3 seconds on an rk3188 and 3 seconds on a samsung gt9200. really irritating!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure But I think this is due to some caching problem , as it plays for x times and then stops playing . File is not accessible that can be due to multiple reasons :Permissions, corrupt file , wrong file but your seems to be a different case.

Can you use [reset](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#reset%28%29) and try again

> public void reset () Since: API Level 1
>
> Resets the MediaPlayer to its uninitialized state. After calling this
>   method, you will have to initialize it again by setting the data
>   source and calling prepare().

Comment: I will do that but perhaps it might be necessary to explain a bit further, the actual playback of the video is carried out in a different activity to preserve the previous layout and activity. When playback is finished, finish() is called on the activity and it (should be) destroyed. Therefore calling reset wouldn't really matter would it? But.. will give it a go.

Comment: OK so you are building/copying your file in one activity and playing in another, just out of curiosity are you checking before playing that file exists. Some problem might be occurring at the end of building/copying that file.

Comment: The file is actually downloaded if it doesn't exist, so it is definitely checked if it exists (and the player will not play if it doesn't exist, it will instead download it with an asynctask and the app will carry on with the loop if not present).

The file definitely exists as well, as evidenced by the 37 times it plays beforehand. It's a real headscratcher alright, but unfortunately, it is something I need to solve.

Comment: The video plays fine through the stock media player when the file is opened in the file manager or gallery. Last time it was the 37th time, I will tell you shortly if it consistently stops on 37th. I only just setup a counter when I created this question.

Comment: It's a real headscratcher. Why after 37 th ? when every time same file is played. there is simple check to find out if something is wrong with your video view play it using some other media player. This will help you to pinpoint the error. what I meant was keep playing through the stock media player till it crashes

Comment: Got to 46 that time. Still haven't tried playing it over and over in local player yet.

Comment: See update 2 above. Works on other Android devices, just not the one I want it to work on... sigh.

Answer (score 0):

OK well, I never did resolve this to my ultimate satisfaction, especially since it was particular to a device. In the end I just added in exception handling so it would not crash when failing to play the video and just skip it and try again next time.

The video does play in the loop the next time around, so I am guessing it is something specific to the device.