# MediaPlayer starts throwing unknown errors after some time

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-videoview

I have an app with lots of short videos being played all over. Some of them using `VideoView`, some just a `TextureView` with a `MediaPlayer`. This works fine, except after a while, any new attempt to play a video using either of those methods fails with `MEDIA_ERROR_UNKNOWN` and a seemingly random value for `extra`. It seems to happen a lot earlier on lower-end devices too. It starts working again after killing the app.

Some more info that might be useful:

- Most of the videos are set to loop
- There can sometimes be more than one video loaded at a time, though it still breaks even if I avoid those situations
- I call `release()` on the `MediaPlayer`s I use when the activity or fragment they're in is destroyed, so I'd assume it's not a problem with leaking resources or something like that
- All the videos being played are in the app's local storage
- On some devices, I sometimes get an `IOException` saying `setDataSourceFD` failed instead, though I couldn't get it to happen to post the exact message here
- My min sdk is 21 and target is 29

From the googling I've done so far, the only thing that seemed remotely related I found was that the video is in an unsupported format, but that can't be the case here, as it sometimes fails on videos that were played just fine before, sometimes even on the same run.
There's also [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11555537/android-video-stops-playing-after-multiple-plays-error-1-2147483648), though that seems to be specific to a device, whereas I see this on anything I try it on, from emulators, through low-ends to high-ends, with the time it takes to break generally being longer the higher-end the device is.

This has been eluding me for a few days now, so any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: i have done something similar, i would suggest you to do more profiling, seems like its a resource usage bug as you mentioned. 
also consider managing all MediaPlayer instances with one class, this was helpful in my app. good luck

Comment: I tried using a singleton for `MediaPlayer` management and so far it seems to have helped, albeit with some hiccups - mainly that I still get errors all the time, but this way I can just `release()` the broken player and try again, which seems to work. I haven't implemented this in the whole app yet tho as that's going to be a *lot* of work, but I guess I'll give it a go and see if it works...